tax in token result ds-math-sub-underflow
function swapTokenForFund(uint256 tokenAmount) private lockTheSwap {
        emit LogTaxWalletBalance(_balances[address(this)]);
        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = address(this); // 当前 token
        path[1] = _swapRouter.WETH(); // BNB
        if (tokenAmount > _balances[address(this)]){
            tokenAmount = _balances[address(this)];
        }
        _approve(address(this), address(_swapRouter), tokenAmount);
        try _swapRouter.swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
            tokenAmount,
            0,
            path,
            address(this),
            block.timestamp+180
        ) {
            emit LogString("Swap succeeded");
        } catch Error(string memory reason) {
            emit LogString(string(abi.encodePacked("Swap failed: ", reason)));
    
        } catch (bytes memory lowLevelData) {
            emit LogString(string(abi.encodePacked("Swap failed with low level error: ", lowLevelData)));
    
        }
        emit LogTaxWalletBalance(_balances[address(this)]); 
        emit LogTaxSwap(tokenAmount); // 记录税费转换结果
    }
    
function _handleTokenTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 amount) internal virtual {
        claimRelease(from);
        uint256 fromBalance = _balances[from];
        require(fromBalance >= amount, "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance");
        unchecked {
            _balances[from] = fromBalance - amount;
        }
        uint side = 0;
        uint256 taxAmount = amount * fee / 100;
        uint256 Ramount = amount;
        if (!_feeWhiteList[from] && !_feeWhiteList[to]) {
            Ramount = amount - taxAmount;
            _balances[address(this)] = taxAmount;
            emit LogAA("amount * fee / 100: ", address(this) , taxAmount );
            _approve(address(this), address(_swapRouter), amount); 

            emit LogAA("_balances[address(this)]: ", address(this) , _balances[address(this)] );
            emit LogTaxWalletBalance(_balances[ address(this)]); 
            // 记录税费钱包余额
            
             // 0x10ed43c718714eb63d5aa57b78b54704e256024e   0xbb4cdb9cbd36b01bd1cbaebf2de08d9173bc095c
            emit LogAA("_balances[from]: ", from ,_balances[from]);
            emit LogAA("_balances[to]: ", to ,_balances[to]);
        }
        if (isPair(from) && !isRouter(to)){
               _balances[to]+=Ramount
            }
        } else { 
             emit LogString("sell");
             if(isPair(to)){
                 side = 2; //sell
             }
            _balances[to] += Ramount;
        }
     
        emit LogBoolFlag("from_feeWhiteList",from, !_feeWhiteList[from] );
        emit LogBoolFlag("https://remix.ethereum.org/assets/img/deployAndRun.webpto_feeWhiteList",to, !_feeWhiteList[to] );
        // 添加税费逻辑
        if (!inSwap){
            uint256 contractTokenBalance = _balances[address(this)];
            if (contractTokenBalance > 0){
                swapTokenForFund(contractTokenBalance);
            }
        }
        emit Trade(from,to,side,amount);
    }
    
function _transfer(address from, address to, uint256 amount) internal virtual {
        require(from != address(0), "ERC20: transfer from the zero address");
        require(to != address(0), "ERC20: transfer to the zero address");
        _handleTokenTransfer(from, to, amount);

        emit Transfer(from, to, amount);
    }


when it run the swaptokenforfund i get an error
ds-math-sub-underflow
here is the tX
https://bscscan.com/tx/0xf944badb89e7ac33357baec0cb09a8d34fa247a511b905e76c400cf1f7ed669a#eventlog
